# mysql_tzinfo_to_sql command not found with mysql server 5.6.46 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04

I installed mysql version 5.6 using this tutorial - https://gist.github.com/Ajorona/e44ca0d0e9cfa055976ea91d9a2cba2a 
and this is the version of the mysql:

```
mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.46, for linux-glibc2.12 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

the Ubuntu version:

```
 cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

and now, I am trying to create timezone related tables in 'mysql' database by running :

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install tzdata
$ mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo > tzinfo.sql
$ mysql -u root -D mysql -proot < tzinfo.sql
```

but I get the error-

```
 mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo > /home/ubuntu/tzinfo.sql

Command 'mysql_tzinfo_to_sql' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install mysql-server-5.7                 
sudo apt install mariadb-server-10.1              
sudo apt install percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7
```

But, i need the sql version to 5.6 for a project. Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: You haven't installed MySQL using the Ubuntu package manager so can't use it either to install further MySQL-related stuff. However, the `tar.gz` download in the tutorial clearly has a `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` file in the `bin` directory. (Out of curiosity, are you really doing some work that requires 5.6 and cannot be done with 5.7?)

Comment: was trying to setup a new project which had mentioned to install version 5.6 in the documentation, just checked now, 5.7 should also work.will update the version back to 5.7